# Как встроить API в телеграм-бота?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Как сделать так что бы бот удалял сообщения или банил участника группы, если он есть в этой базе? https://cas.chat/api
Могу ли я добавить это в свой скрипт?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import telegram
import time

def main():
    bot = telegram.Bot(token='token')
    chat_id=-10015422663
    from_chat_id=-10021424213
    message_id=25

    interval=60
    while True:

        bot.forward_message(chat_id, from_chat_id, message_id)
        time.sleep(interval)

if name == 'main':
    main()
```

Comment: советую убирать токен при публикации кода

Comment: ... в следующий раз, потому что история редактирования сохраняется. А сейчас этот токен заблочить и выпустить новый.

Answer (score 1):

Так как я не знаком с tgApi вот прототип кода, вам нужно дополнить функции `get_users(chat_id)` и `ban(user_id)`:

```
import telegram
import time
from requests import get
def get_users(chat_id):
    # Функция которая выдаст список участников
    pass

def ban(user_id):
    # Функция которая забанит
    pass

def main():
    bot = telegram.Bot(token='token')
    chat_id=-10015422663
    from_chat_id=-10021424213
    message_id=25

    interval=60
    while True:

        bot.forward_message(chat_id, from_chat_id, message_id)
        for user_id in get_users(chat_id):
            response = eval(get(f'https://api.cas.chat/check?user_id={user_id}').text.replace('false', 'False'))['ok']
            if response: ban(user_id)
        time.sleep(interval)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```